# Broadcast version of in() function or in operator?

Tags: julia

Consider an array, say 0 to 4. I want to test if each element is in a list and return an array of booleans. A call to `in` returns a single boolean, because this left-hand side array is not an element of the right-hand side array:

```
> a = 0:4;
> a in [1, 2]
false
```

Does Julia have a broadcast version of the `in()` function or the `in` operator that returns an array like this call to `map` and a lambda function?

```
> map(x -> x in [1,2], a)
5-element Array{Bool,1}:
 false
  true
  true
 false
 false
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use broadcasting, but you have to tell Julia that the second argument should not be iterated over, so you should do:

```
julia> in.(a, [[1,2]])
5-element BitArray{1}:
 false
  true
  true
 false
 false
```

or

```
julia> in.(a, Ref{Vector{Int}}([1,2]))
5-element BitArray{1}:
 false
  true
  true
 false
 false
```

Both will work under Julia 0.6.3 and 0.7.

Similarly, the `∈` operator (`\in`<kbd>TAB</kbd>, synonymous with the `in` function) allows for broadcasting using infix notation.

```
julia> 0:4 .∈ [[1,2]]
5-element BitArray{1}:
 false
  true
  true
 false
 false
```

Comment: I believe `in.(a, Ref([1,2]))` is enough (and equivalent).

Comment: @fredrikekre no, `in.(a, Ref([1,2]))` returns only one `true`, not two.

Comment: In Julia 0.7  `Ref([1,2])` is deprecated so soon this, I would say confusing construct, will be disallowed. The reason is that `Ref([1,2])` is the same as `Ref([1,2], 1)` in Julia 0.6.3 which gets you only `1` from `[1,2]`.